# GNU Make rule that executes only if target exists?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, mount-point

In a fairly complex Makefile, I'd occasionally like to invoke certain rules only if a target *does* exist.  For example, I may have created a local directory and used `losetup` to mount a file onto it.  I'd like to leave the mountpoint and the directory open while working on them, but automatically close them before certain operations.

When it's time to package things up, I want to `sync` the mounted file, `umount` it, and then do something with the underlying file.  Is there are way to invert the sense of a rule so that it executes only if a particular target *is* present?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about something like:

```
target = $(wildcard somefile)

$(target): ; @echo build $@

.PHONY: $(target)
```

Comment: Amazing!  I already have something equivalent to your `$(target)` to perform the original mounting and mapping, but it's easy to use `$(patsubst )` to correct that.

Comment: Sorry I don't yet have enough rep to upvote your answer.